# for statement not returning values from array

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement, for-loop, syntax

I'm trying to Write a function `translate()` that will double every consonant. For example, translate("this is fun") should return the string "tthhiss iss ffunn".

The code below worked fine until I tried to add the array/second `for` loop. When run it now returns a syntax error of the `<` in the second for loop? This clearly isn't the problem but after several attempts I'm still at a loss of where the problem really lies?

Any ideas where I'm going wrong? Thank you in advance.

```
var vowel = ['a','e','i','o','u'];

function translate(text) {

var newText = '';
var isVowel = false;

for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
        isVowel = false;
    for (var x = 0; < vowel.length; x++) {
        if (text[i] == vowel[x]) 
        {
            isVowel = true;
        }
    }
    if (isVowel != true) {
        newText = newText + text[i] + text[i];
    } else {
        newText = newText + text[i];
    }
}
return newText;
}

console.log(translate('cat sat on the mat'));
```

Comment: you're missing an x; you just have < vowel.length there..

Comment: You missing an x. Syntax might be wrong.

Comment: `This clearly isn't the problem` Many people have pointed out the problem. There is an x missing.

Answer (score 0):

Syntax error because you forgot a `x`.

Change

```
for (var x = 0; < vowel.length; x++) {
```

to

```
for (var x = 0; x < vowel.length; x++) {
```

Answer (score 0):

You missed an `x` in the second forloop

You got it like this:

```
for (var x = 0; < vowel.length; x++)
```

make it like this:

```
for (var x = 0; x < vowel.length; x++)
```